# I can't configure lando with xdebug

Tags: xdebug, lando

I am trying to setup Xdebug with a Lando Drupal site. I have tried a lot of different lando configurations but no matter what I do I can't get xdebug to show up in my phpinfo. The current configuration I have is:

```
name: content-engine-1
recipe: pantheon
config:
  framework: drupal8
  site: content-engine-1
  id: bdfe297a-e96b-401d-b932-158854085e0e
  xdebug: true
  php: .lando.php.ini
services:
  appserver:
    xdebug: true
    overrides:
      environment:
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=appserver"
```

here's the .lando.php.ini file

```
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/var/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

here is the output from phpinfo():
[phpinfo output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDVUg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Documentation https://docs.lando.dev/config/php.html#configuration
it should be

```
name: content-engine-1
recipe: pantheon
config:
  framework: drupal8
  site: content-engine-1
  id: bdfe297a-e96b-401d-b932-158854085e0e
  xdebug: true
  config:
     php: .lando.php.ini
```